# What changes\setups I need to make to run java in docker over WSL(windows-subsystem-for-linux)?

Tags: java, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the docker command in windows command line successfully but when I run the same command in windows-subsystem-for-linux it shows class not found exception.

windows:
docker run -it --cpus 4 -v ${PWD}:/app --workdir /app adoptopenjdk/openjdk11 java -cp C:\path\to\class Helloworld.java

WSL:
docker run -it --cpus 4 -v ${PWD}:/app --workdir /app adoptopenjdk/openjdk11 java -cp /path/to/class Helloworld.java

Expected output:

Hello world!!

Error:

Could not find or load main class Helloworld.java

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Helloworld.java

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the path may be wrong

> You can also access your local machine’s filesystem from within the
>   Linux Bash shell – you’ll find your local drives mounted under the
>   /mnt folder. For example, your C: drive is mounted under /mnt/c:

-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#what-can-i-do-with-wsl

Comment: Path is correct I have verified. Also tried after copy it to /temp folder but same result.